# Add custom input_renderer to an existing attribute

Tags: magento-1.7, product-attribute, renderer

I've been searching for 2 hours now... I want to use a custom_renderer on the product view for the "color" attribute.

Many answers posted here are adding new attributes and setting "input_renderer" in an install script.

OK but what if my attribute already exists ? I don't want to drop it (and lose all its value).

It there a way to do that ? An event to use maybe ? I only want to change the renderer for this attribute and not for every  input.

I hope i was clear enough. Feel free to ask any questions that may be needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your install/upgrade script, this is how it's done for **existing attributes**:

```
$installer->updateAttribute(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY,'color','frontend_input_renderer','some/class_name_alias');
```

I hope this helps you out!